# Rest API redundancy with promises

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, promise

if I had a few async `fetch()`'s and their respective promises at hand, I seek to implement a function such that the earliest resolution into `Response()` with a status code 200 would return that very `Response` and drop everything else to the limbo of garbage collector. On the other hand, if none of those resolves with code 200, the latest resolution with non-200 code is returned.

What's the most elegant way to achieve that? I am not big on js - I believe there should've been somewhat widely used pattern...

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect use case for [`Promise.any`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/any). It fulfills with the fastest fulfillment from a set of promises, and rejects only once all of them are rejected (in contrast to `Promise.race`). So you'd use

```
const urls = […];
const fastestResponse = await Promise.any(urls.map(async url => {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  if (response.status == 200) return response;
  else throw new Error(response.statusText+' response: '+await response.text());
}));
```

Answer (score -1):

I ended up with this code

```
const resp = await Promise.all([

    fetch(new Request(req.url, init)),
    fetch(new Request(req.url, init2)),
])

if (resp[0].status < resp[1].status) return resp[0]

return resp[1]
```

Turned out promise wouldn't eve reject (in Cloudflare worker) - they just give you their custom http code e.g., 521 if connection couldn't be established for example. Erroneous promise can resolve faster than a good one in this case, so throwing anything to GC wouldn't be a good option. Parallel wait is the best we can get.